# sympyで作成されるグラフについて

Tags: python, sympy

初歩的な質問で恐縮です。

sympyのplot_implicit関数を使って陰関数のグラフを作成する際の質問です。
以下のコードのとおり、pointsに格納されている座標を連続して読み込んで一つの
グラフに表示させる際はどのようにすれば良いのでしょうか。
また、pointsの座標点も同時に表示させたいのですが可能でしょうか。

現状、plot_implicitにて描画させているのは単純な円ですでの、別の手段で実現
可能でしょうが、今後複雑な式の描画も検討しているためplot_implicitを使いつ
つ実現したいです。

以下にサンプルコードを記載しますが、これではpontsの最後の座標を使った円しか
描画されません。

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import plot
from sympy.plotting import plot_implicit

points = np.array([[10,20], [20, 75], [45, 15], [70, 53], [90, 30]])
weights = np.array([5, 5.1, 5.2, 4.9, 4.8])

x, y = symbols("x y")

for i in range(len(points)):
 G = (x-points[i][0])**2 + (y-points[i][1])**2 - weights[i]**2   
 p2 = plot_implicit(G, (x,0,100), (y,0,100), show=False, line_color='r')
 p2.extend(p2)

p2.show()
```

Comment: metropolis様、わざわざお調べ頂きありがとうございました。大変勉強になりました。早速実装してみたいと思います。まだまだ初心者で理解が追い付かない点も多いですが、これからもよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下の様なコードですと、p2 が毎回変更されてしまいますので、p2 は最後に生成した ImplicitSeries インスタンスだけになってしまいます。

```
p2 = plot_implicit(...)
p2.extend(p2)
```

ですので、以下の様に書き変えてみると良いかと思います。

```
for i in range(len(points)):
  G = (x-points[i][0])**2 + (y-points[i][1])**2 - weights[i]**2
  p = plot_implicit(G, (x,0,100), (y,0,100), show=False, line_color='r')
  if i == 0:
    p2 = p
  else:
    p2.extend(p)
```

**追記**

> pointsの座標点も同時に描画したいのですが、ご存知でしょうか。
>
> sympy だけで処理しようとすると、座標点を線で結んでしまいますね。。。matplotlib で sympy の式をプロットする様にすれば上手く行くかもしれませんが、少し調べてみます。

sympy の `plot_implicit()` の内部処理を眺めると、方程式から決定される矩形領域を塗り潰しています(fill)。その矩形領域の 4 隅の座標は `ImplicitSeries.get_points()` メソッドで取得できるので、取り出した座標データを matplotlib で処理できる様な形式に再構成します。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *

points = np.array([[10,20], [20, 75], [45, 15], [70, 53], [90, 30]])
weights = np.array([5, 5.1, 5.2, 4.9, 4.8])
rangex, rangey = (0, 100), (0, 100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(rangex)
ax.set_ylim(rangey)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

x, y = symbols("x y")
for (px, py), w in zip(points, weights):
  ax.plot(px, py, marker='.', markersize=3, color='blue')
  ax.annotate('(%d, %d)' % (px, py), 
     xy=(px, py), xytext=(-15, 15),
     textcoords='offset points', ha='right', va='bottom',
     bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.2', fc='yellow', alpha=0.5),
     arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0'))
  G = (x-px)**2 + (y-py)**2 - w**2
  p = plot_implicit(G, (x,)+rangex, (y,)+rangey, show=False)[0].get_points()[0]
  px, py = [], []
  for (ix, iy) in p:
    px.extend([ix.start, ix.start, ix.end, ix.end, None])
    py.extend([iy.start, iy.end, iy.end, iy.start, None])
  ax.fill(px, py, facecolor='red')

plt.show()
```

[image: sympy の実行例]

Comment: 大変助かりました。pointsの座標点も同時に描画したいのですが、ご存知でしょうか。

Comment: sympy だけで処理しようとすると、座標点を線で結んでしまいますね。。。matplotlib で sympy の式をプロットする様にすれば上手く行くかもしれませんが、少し調べてみます。