# SymPy と SciPy におけるグラフの統合

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy, scipy

以下のサンプルコードにて、5つの座標点からなるボロノイ図を`scipy.spatial.voronoi_plot_2d`を使って生成します。

このグラフ上に`sympy.plotting.plot_implicit`を使って任意の陰関数（双曲線等）を描画したいのですが、やり方が分からず困っております。

適切な方法をご存知でしたら、ご教授願います。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d

points = np.array([[10,20], [20, 75], [45, 15], [70, 53], [90, 30]])
weights = np.array([20, 5, 5, 5, 5])
vor = Voronoi(points)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
voronoi_plot_2d(vor, ax = ax)

for i in range(len(points)):
 c = plt.Circle(points[i], weights[i], fc="none", ec='k')
 ax.add_patch(c)

for j, p in enumerate(points):
 plt.text(p[0]-5, p[1]+5, j, ha = 'right')


plt.xlim([0, 100])
plt.ylim([0, 100])

plt.show()
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローでは、編集画面でコード部分を範囲選択し、エディタ上部の `{}` を押すと自動的にコードブロックとして装飾できますので、次から是非お試しください :)　特に Python のコードはそのままだとインデントが消えて表示されてしまいますので、コードブロックにして頂けると助かります。

Comment: 本題とは関係ありませんが、このコードはこのままだと `weights` が未定義ではないでしょうか？

Comment: nekketsuuu様、大変ご丁寧な解説を頂きありがとうございました。大変勉強になりました。早速使わせて頂きたく存じます。また、weightsのご指摘ありがとうございます。大変失礼致しました。修正致しました。

Comment: metropolis様、この度も解決法を提示頂きありがとうございました。また、過去の回答の参考事例もありがとうございます。早速試してみたく存じます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sympy/plotting/plot.py`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/plotting/plot.py) の docstring に書かれているように、ある程度新しい SymPy であれば `Plot._backend` を使うことによってバックエンドの matplotlib オブジェクトを触ることができます。マニュアルには書かれていない汚いやり方ですが、私が調べた限りだと現状この方法しか用意されていないように見えました。

一度 `_backend` を得てしまえば、`_backend.fig` や `_backend.ax` を使うことで SymPy が使ったプロットにアクセスできます。ですから、この Axes に新しくプロットを作れば上から別のプロットを描くことができるようです。

以下、私の環境では動作したサンプルコードです。半径50の円を `plot_implicit()` してみました。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
from sympy import plot_implicit, Eq
from sympy.abc import x, y

plt.ion()

splt = plot_implicit(Eq(x**2 + y**2, 2500), (x, 0, 100), (y, 0, 100))
ax = splt._backend.ax

points = np.array([[10,20], [20, 75], [45, 15], [70, 53], [90, 30]])
vor = Voronoi(points)
fig = voronoi_plot_2d(vor, ax=ax)

for i in range(len(points)):
    c = plt.Circle(points[i], 10.0, fc="none", ec='k')
    ax.add_patch(c)

for j, p in enumerate(points):
    ax.text(p[0]-5, p[1]+5, j, ha = 'right')

ax.set_xlim([0, 100])
ax.set_ylim([0, 100])

fig.canvas.draw()
#fig.canvas.flush_events()  # 必要かも？
plt.show(block=True)
```

いくつか注意点です。

- `voronoi_plot_2d()` してから `plot_implicit()` する順番でも良さそうなのですが、そうすると `splt._backend.ax.get_child()` から順番にボロノイ図の方の Axes へ `add_patch()` せねばならず、またこのとき Figure が 2 つできてしまうので上手く処理する必要がありそうでした (`plot_implicit(..., show=False)` しても良いのですが、そうすると `_backend` が生成されないため [`_backend = splt.backend(splt)` する](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/b69d4c27f298766f1f9c5f6bb17dcf7ae71bb67b/sympy/plotting/plot.py#L196)必要が出てきます)。このため先に `plot_implicit()` しています。
- 詳しい理由まで調べていませんが、この方法だと matplotlib をインタラクティブにしないと追加の要素が描画されないようでした。このため `plt.ion()` を実行しており、また `show()` したときに即時終了しないよう `show(block=True)` しています。

参考: [Sympy and plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40747474/5989200) -- Stack Overflow

私の環境: Python 3.6.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit), SymPy 1.1.1, matplotlib 2.0.2, SciPy 0.19.1, NumPy 1.13.1

Answer (score 4):

[「sympyで作成されるグラフについて」に対する回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/48043/16894) と同じ手法で双曲線を描いてみました。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
from sympy import *

points = np.array([[10,20], [20, 75], [45, 15], [70, 53], [90, 30]])
weights = np.array([5, 5.1, 5.2, 4.9, 4.8])
vor = Voronoi(points)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
voronoi_plot_2d(vor, ax = ax)

for i in range(len(points)):
  c = plt.Circle(points[i], weights[i], fc="none", ec='k')
  ax.add_patch(c)

for j, p in enumerate(points):
  plt.text(p[0]-5, p[1]+5, j, ha = 'right')

## Draw hyperbola curve
x, y = symbols("x y")
G = (x-50)**2/16 - (y-50)**2/9 - 10
r = (0, 100)
p = plot_implicit(G, (x,)+r, (y,)+r, show=False)[0].get_points()[0]
px, py = [], []
for (ix, iy) in p:
  px.extend([ix.start, ix.start, ix.end, ix.end, None])
  py.extend([iy.start, iy.end, iy.end, iy.start, None])
ax.fill(px, py, facecolor='red')

plt.xlim([0, 100])
plt.ylim([0, 100])
ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

[image: Voronoi and hyperbola curve]